# Questions about conditionals without a comparison

Tags: c++

What does these conditions mean in C++:

```
if (whereto)
if (!nE)
for (cur=first; cur; cur=cur->next)
if (del->prev)
```

I am still beginner in C++. learned the basic conditions but those conditions are not clear for me.  What do the expressions `whereto`, `!ne`, `cur`, and `del->prov` mean in a conditional

Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @Ron sorry man tried to write bold some people now what is the question.

Comment: What are the types of the variables in these expressions? Why are you confused?

Comment: @jaggedSpire the problem is I usually write for example if(whereto =0) .. but now I don't see the condition of the if or if(!=ne).

Comment: @Kashan No problem.

Comment: ***for example if(whereto =0)*** you mean  `if(whereto == 0)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those expressions are being evaluated in a boolean context.

Here, a value of 0 (or NULL) is false, while any non-zero (or non-null) value is true.

So the above is equivalent to:

```
if (whereto != 0)
if (nE == 0)
for (cur=first; cur != NULL; cur=cur->next)
if (del->prev != NULL)
```

Comment: so by writing if(whereto) , we mean if(whereto==null)?

Comment: ***so by writing if(whereto) , we mean if(whereto==null)?*** It means  `if(whereto != nullptr)` or `if(whereto != 0)`

Comment: @drescherjm thanks man. Now I got it. thanks everyone.

Comment: @Kashan Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.